# I can not find the octave.exe after installing octave

Tags: python, octave

When installing oct2py library on Python, I was required to have GNU Octave installed in my path, in another word, setx PATH "%PATH%; where the folder  has the file “octave.exe”.

However, I can not find the octave.exe after installing octave using the installation packages released in https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/#install and I have tried all the three installation packages for Windows-64.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look in `octave.bat` which should be in your Octave binaries directory.

Comment: "Octave should be started from the "Octave (GUI)" or "Octave (CLI)" launchers - or from the octave.bat file in the Octave binaries directory. "

Comment: [How do I start Octave GUI from zip file install](//superuser.com/q/1353256)

Answer (score 2):

The installation of Octave on Windows is rather odd, and Chocolatey guys also had [a lot of difficulties](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-package-requests/issues/487) with it. Unfortunately, the ESI people are also not very supportive of the project as it seems they are using the workforce to develop in house proprietary software...

Anyway if you try to locate the executable from the shortcut file in the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GNU Octave 5.1.0.0
```

via `open file location` in the right-click context menu, it misguides you to `wscript` executable in `C:\Windows\System32` folder. However, the actual installation folder is in the C root (usually this should be the default). The path to executables should be

```
C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin
```

and

```
C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw32\bin
```

for 64bit and 32bit versions of `octave-cli.exe` and `octave-gui.exe` respectively.